# iOS browser crashing when using -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

Tags: ios, ipad, css

When making a scrollable div, for iOS devices, momentum scroll doesn't work - so you must use the 'beta' -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; property.

However, this seems to crash the browser for me - not immediately, but seemingly randomly. Removing all of the -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; properties stop the browser from crashing.

I've tried using iScroll, touchSwipe, and a few other plugins that I can't remember the name of, but have either been too cumbersome to implement (I have a very short timeframe for development) or haven't worked as desired.

Does anyone experience the same problem, and if they have, have you found a solution?

Comment: `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` works from **iOS 5.1** and higher. It's got a huge performance boost on **iOS 6**. On iOS 5 the performance is quite bad, so when using this on multiple items on a single page or using it together with 3D translation may cause the browser to crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I happened to me on bigger  list with about over 100

elements.
When I removed it it works, but without the momentum scrolling ofcourse.

I tested on iOS5 and latest iOS6, on both an iPod Touch 4.1 and iPad 2, it seems that on the Touch I get the Safari crash more often, but on the iPad it also happens.

It seems like an Apple bug they didn't properly solve.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this happening when I had it applied to multiple elements on the page... I dropped it down to being applied only on the "active" div, and it doesn't crash anymore. Lame.

Comment: same here. getting deeper into iOS webapp dev; those fancy css things are a pain in the ass. sad but real true.

Answer (score -1):

```
let content = document.querySelector(".content");
if (content.scrollTop <= 0) {
    content.scrollTop = 1;
} else if (content.scrollTop >= content.scrollHeight - content.clientHeight) {
    content.scrollTop = content.scrollHeight - content.clientHeight - 1;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.